# Is there any difference between the align-items property value flex-start and start in flexbox layout?

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 200px;
            align-items: start; 
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .flex-start-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 200px;
            align-items: flex-start; 
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .item {
            width: 50px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>align-items</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>align-items: start</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
    
    <h2>align-items: flex-start</h2>
    <div class="flex-start-container">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of what I did.
I tried changing flex-direction: column; and flex-direction: row; but can't see any difference
I saw somewhere mentioned that start and flex-start are the same, but they are outdated. I don’t know if this is true.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are [explained well here](https://csslayout.news/whats-the-difference-between-the-alignment-values-of-start-flex-start-and-self-start/), but you’re unlikely to notice any difference unless you’re doing advanced operations like reversing the flex direction or using a right-to-left language.

Answer (score 0):

If "`flex-direction`" is `row-reverse` then `flex-start` will be right of screen.

But "`start`" always means current language direction's start, for english being always left of screen, ignoring `flex-direction`.